# Renaming a subroutine in a Fortran module when using iso_c_binding

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am working with two Fortran modules. The first one contains a subroutine `foo`:

```
module fmod1

  contains

  subroutine foo(i)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(inout) :: i

    i=i+1

  end subroutine foo

end module fmod1
```

The second one also contains a subroutine called `foo` which calls the `foo` of the first module, renamed as `foo_first`:

```
module fmod2
  use fmod1, only : foo_first => foo

  contains

  subroutine foo(i)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(inout) :: i

    i=i+2
    call foo_first(i)

  end subroutine foo

end module fmod2
```

When I compile these with gfortran to get two object files and then look inside them with nm, I see the expected result:

```
fmod1.o:
0000000000000020 s EH_frame1
0000000000000000 T ___fmod1_MOD_foo

fmod2.o:
0000000000000030 s EH_frame1
                 U ___fmod1_MOD_foo
0000000000000000 T ___fmod2_MOD_foo
```

I then have no problem in writing a Fortran program which loads the second module and calls the `foo` within it (`___fmod2_MOD_foo`, which itself calls `___fmod1_MOD_foo`).

My problem comes when I try to do the same thing from a C program using `iso_c_binding`. I change the second module by adding `bind(c)` to the subroutine:

```
module fmod2
  use iso_c_binding
  use fmod1, only : foo_first => foo

  contains

  subroutine foo(i) bind(c)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(inout) :: i

    i=i+2
    call foo_first(i)

  end subroutine foo

end module fmod2
```

Running nm again on the object files now gives this:

```
fmod1.o:
0000000000000020 s EH_frame1
0000000000000000 T ___fmod1_MOD_foo

fmod2.o:
0000000000000030 s EH_frame1
0000000000000000 T _foo
```

i.e., the second module no longer seems to require the first module. When I try experimenting with calling `foo` from the second module from a C program it becomes apparent that the subroutine, instead of calling `foo` from the first module, is calling itself in an infinite loop.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something which I shouldn't be doing?

Comment: it's gfortran 5.3.0

Comment: Could you try adding bind(c,name="foo") or bind(c,name="foo_f") and see the output of nm foo2.o? (On my computers, the result depends on the version of gfortran...)

Comment: For bind(c,name="foo") I get the same problematic results, while for bind(c,name="foo_f") I get the correct result:

    fmod2.o:
    0000000000000030 s EH_frame1
                     U ___fmod1_MOD_foo
    0000000000000000 T _foo_f

Comment: Same for me with gfortran6.3 on mac10.11. Interestingly,  bind(c) (as in the question) works with older gfortran4.8 (on a Linux box). On the other hand, ifort-16 and oracle studio fortran 12.5 work for all patterns. ... hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [GCC Bug 79485](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79485). I have already reported very similar and very probably related bugs before ([ICE with binding-name equal to the name of a use-associated procedure](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66695) and [Wrong subroutine called, clash of specific procedure name and binding-name](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77746)). Unfortunately the gfortran developers are only a few and very busy and did not fix this problem yet. If they see other people encountering it they might consider it with a slightly higher priority.

Comment: Status: Fixed (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79485)

Answer (score 2):

When you add BIND(C) to the procedure, you are specifying (indirectly) the binding name instead of the compiler applying its own rules (that include the module name).

It's not that "the second module no longer seems to require the first module" but that you've changed the binding name of the routine in the second module. You haven't touched the binding name of foo in the first module (which is not its local name due to the rename.)

That said, the compiler ought to know the binding name of foo in the first module, referenced through its local name, and put out the correct name in the object for the call. From what other commenters have said, the version of gfortran you're using may have a bug here. Try a newer one.

Comment: There are several similar problems already reported by me. They started in gfortran 4.9 but have not been fixed yet. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66695  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77746  It may all have a common origin.